# Reading the value from select

Tags: jquery, html-select

I have around 30 of select form like this with different id(number_x):

```
<div class="holder">
    <select class="start" id="number_x" maxlength=5 size=1 value>
        <option value><option>
        <option value>1<option>
        <option value>2<option>
        <option value>3<option>
        <option value>4<option>
        <option value>5<option>
    </select>
</div>    
<div class="holder">
    <select class="start" id="number_x+1" maxlength=5 size=1 value>
        <option value><option>
        <option value>1<option>
        <option value>2<option>
        <option value>3<option>
        <option value>4<option>
        <option value>5<option>
    </select>
</div>
```

After the value from 1 to 5 is chosen I need to read it with jquery, so I can write it in table for future calculations.

```
--pseudocode (val() dont work)
$(button).click{
    for(x++){
        tab[x]= $('.holder .start#number_x').val();
     }
}
```

All I need is just to read the value from the select.start

Comment: You should learn javascript before you use jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your html syntax  is not valid.

change

```
  <option value><option>
        <option value>1<option>
```

to

```
 <option value=""><option>
   <option value="">1<option>...and so on
```

Then calling `val()` works

[**See Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/fRUUd/1371/)

Comment: Thank you, it all works now. Also, the mistake was because I forgot _ in class name :) Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

For the various IDs that is starting from _number_x_, 
Try this pseudo code:

```
$(button).click{
    for(x++){
        tab[x]= $('select[id^=number_x]').val();
     }
}
```

**OR**

```
$(button).click{
   for(x++){
      tab[x]= $('.holder .start#number_x' + x '"').val();
   }
}
```

And for the HTML mark up

Do this

```
<option value=""><option>
<option value="">1<option>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should either use

```
<option><option>
<option>1<option>
```

or

```
<option value=''><option>
<option value='1'>1<option>
```

and you can use `val()` function in jquery to get the values

Answer (score 0):

Add all your select box inside a table and you can loop through the select boxes in each form using:

```
$('#'+tableId+' select').each(function(){
   selected_value = ($(this).val());
   //add your logic to store it in a table for future calculations
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the attribute starts with selector to target the relevant `<select>` elements. Then just store an `id: value` pair, like so:

```
var selectValues = [];
$('select[id^="number_"]').change(function() {
    selectValues[this.id] = this.value;
});
```

#### [Here's a demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VtxyK/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/2dJAN/86/

Like below you can get the selected values of all select boxes

```
$.each($('select'),function(){
        alert($("option:selected", this).val());
});
```